# Read the volume of speakers?

Tags: java, audio, signal-processing, audio-recording, javasound

I want to read the volume level from the speakers. I can't figure out how to get the data that is being sent to the speaker, however. I have been able to do this for my Microphone using this method and by reading data from a TargetDataLine. I have no idea how to do this for the speakers though. I want to read the data being sent to the speakers (perhaps through a SourceDataLine?) I tried using a SourceDataLine to get the amplitude, but my example code is not working it keep returning -1. Any suggestions?
Example Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JProgressBar bar = new JProgressBar();
    frame.getContentPane().add(bar);
    frame.pack();
    //frame.show();
    AudioFormat audio = new AudioFormat(8000.0F,16,1,true,false);
    //DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, audio);
    DataLine.Info speakerInfo = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, audio);
    SourceDataLine speaker;
    try {
        speaker = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(speakerInfo);
        speaker.open(audio);
        speaker.start();
        //Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
    } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
   //while(true){
       System.out.println(speaker.getLevel());
   //}      
}

public static int calculateRMSLevel(byte[] audioData){
        long lSum = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<audioData.length; i++)
            lSum = lSum + audioData[i];

        double dAvg = lSum / audioData.length;

        double sumMeanSquare = 0d;
        for(int j=0; j<audioData.length; j++)
            sumMeanSquare = sumMeanSquare + Math.pow(audioData[j] - dAvg, 2d);

        double averageMeanSquare = sumMeanSquare / audioData.length;
        return (int)(Math.pow(averageMeanSquare,0.5d) + 0.5);
    }
```

Comment: The volume of the speakers here is set by a Creative sound system over which the PC has no control, let alone feed-back.

Comment: Surely data is being sent to the speakers though. How can I retrieve that data? (I do not care for data outside the Java Virtual Machine although it would be nice to have access to.) I am not asking for the volume settings, I am asking for the byte data so I can calculate the 'volume' based off of the Root Mean Square.

Comment: On *some* systems there is a Java `DataLine` that corresponds to the speakers.  On others there isn't.  For the latter, it would require installing an audio loop-back in order to get the data.

Comment: I am well aware of the difference between systems. (There is even a difference between OpenJDK-8 and Oracle's JVM on Raspbery Pi for instance), but I am looking at a Windows (7) Implementation

Comment: *"I am well aware of the difference between systems"*  Well good for you. Can you indicate your existing knowledge and the use-case of the code in your question in future, on the basis that those trying to help you (for free) are *not* psychic?

Comment: I apologize, I mistook your italics as condescending.